# Terminator does not keep color profile between splits and new tabs

Tags: gnome-terminator

I just downloaded terminator 0.97. I have several profiles in my configuration file (`~/.config/terminator/config`). I don't usually work with the default profile.

One issue is the problem of keeping the same colour scheme across window splits and when creating new tabs. When I select my `solarized` color scheme and open e.g. a new tab, it automatically jumps to the `default` profile. I used to have a patch downloaded from the internet. However, I can't find it anymore.

Does anybody know about this patch ?
I really love the fact that you can split windows easily.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After spending a decent amount of time looking around, I finally found two solutions starting with the best one mentioned first. I present them for the sake of completeness:

- One has to make sure to have the following line in the terminator configuration file: `always_split_with_profile = True` under the `[global_config]` section. The same issue was brought up [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391353/how-to-set-default-layout-profile-for-terminator-for-tabs-on-start).
- Using the right search terms, I finally found the patch on the following [link](https://code.launchpad.net/~pwes/terminator/new-tabs-inherit-profile):

Comment: mark your answer as best answer

Comment: I have to wait one day before I can do it

Comment: `always_split_with_profile = True` fixed the issue for me. :)